# Writing a bash script. Need some guidance on how to create this

Tags: linux, bash

i am trying to create a bash script for composing a record of first name, middle initial, last name and DOB. I have completed asking the user to input these and providing the outputs. I am now trying to ask if the user has another record to input if they do return to step 2 if not go to 5:
Which step 2 would be inputting the information in again and step 5 will be sorting the information by last name. 
This is the question i am on
Ask the user if they have another record to enter; if so return to 2, if not to 5

I am not looking for specific answers, not asking for you to do my code just a explanation or guidance to help me through this script. Thank you.

This is what I have so far

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo “Enter the required information”
    echo “Enter your First Name”
    read fn
    echo “Enter your Middle Initial”
    read mi
    echo “Enter your last name”
    read ln
    echo “ Enter your DOB”
    read dob
    echo $fn $mi $ln $dob
    echo $fn $mi $ln $dob >> Students.csv
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Can you show us some code we can build on?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: you'd bettet to update your question with details.

Comment: Btw. Replace all `“` with `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this very simple approach to ask for input as long as user confirms with typing `y`:

```
answer="y"

while [[ $answer = "y"* ]]; do
   echo "Enter info:"
   ...
   ...
   ...
   read -p "Type y to add more input: " -r  answer
done

#do stuff with the output, sorting etc.
```

Also, in most cases you want to use `-r` option with `read` in case your input has backslashes in it:
`-r     do not allow backslashes to escape any characters`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I have figured out what I needed to know and completed my script. Much appreciated for the feedback you all gave me.

Comment: @Sam if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.